# Result rawResult.getContents android change url

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the bar code and when the result appears
 I want to replace the site link to my link. I have used this method but do not work with me.

An example of this result after the result opens the website through the Viwa web

https://domainexplem//#/home/11

I just want to change the domain

to https://mydomaain//#/home/11

this my barcode  class

```
 @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Contents = " + rawResult.getContents() +
                ", Format = " + rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(ScannedBarcodeActivity.this, webview.class);
        i.putExtra("url", String.valueOf(rawResult.getContents()));
        if (rawResult.getContents() != null) {
            mylink.replace("domainexplem","mydomaain");
        }
        startActivity(i);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(ScannedBarcodeActivity.this);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

but not work with me  pls  this  app for 
This application will be for schools and I want this feature in the application for easy access to the lesson through the bar code link  go to my site instead of the school site

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url.replace("https://www.aquaserv.ro/index.php?npage=757", "https://www.aquaserv.ro/index.php?npage=758"));
    return false;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.